# Reducing logarithms and exponentials

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I know that...
log(m·n) = log(m) + log(n)
log(m/n) = log(m) – log(n)
log(m·n) = n · log(m)
loga(x)  = logb x / logb a
log(m^n) = n·log(m)
$a^n · a^m = a^{n+m}$
$a^n · b^n = (a·b)^n$
$(a^b)^c=a^{b·c}$
$e^{log(x)} = x$  if $x>0$
$log(e^x) = x$   if $x>0$
And many other.

But what about this one?
$e^{1/log(x)}$

How can I reduce that equation or other similar?

When I write log() I mean neperian logarithm, sometimes written ln()

Comment: I don´t see a way to simplify it.

Comment: It is its own inverse so if $y=e^{1/\log x}$ then $x=e^{1/\log y}$ providing $x$ and $y$ are positive and not $1$

Answer (score 1):

> $$\huge e^{1/\log(x)}=(x^{\log_x(e)})^{\log_x(e)}=x^{[\log_x(e)]^2}$$

$$\frac{\log(e)}{\log(x)}=\log_x(e)\qquad e=x^{\log_x(e)}$$

Comment: Not simpler, but interesting.